# Lint SCSS in VueJS single file component with Webpack

Tags: webpack, sass, vue.js, vue-loader

I'm trying to lint the SCSS styling in the `<style>` tag of VueJS single-file componens using Webpack. I'm attempting to call the webpack loader [scsslint-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scsslint-loader) as preLoader within the vue-loader task of my Webpack build.

The single-file vue.js component....

```
<template lang="pug">
  ...
</template>

<script>
  ...
</script>

<style lang='scss'>

   @import '/scss/core/colors';

  .email {
    color: $primary_color;
    width: 320px;
  }

</style>
```

In Webpack(2.5) the vue-loader config looks like...

```
module: {
  rules: [
    { test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader',
      options: {
        preLoaders: {
          'scss': 'scsslint-loader',
          'sass': 'scsslint-loader'
        },
        loaders: {
          'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
          'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        },
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

The result from running Webpack...

```
undefined:1
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ;
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at linterResults (C:\wamp\www\spreadless\node_modules\scsslint-loader\dist\scsslint-loader.js:20:28)
    at C:\wamp\www\spreadless\node_modules\scsslint-loader\dist\scsslint-loader.js:57:13
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:277:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:897:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:340:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:549:12)
```

Questions are...

- Am I calling the scsslint-loader correctly as a vue-loader{preLoader} within the Webpack config?
- If so any idea on what is causing the no file error

Comment: Worked around this in a completely different manner.